# Open link from webview in browser without header/address bar in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview

Iam developing an app in xamarin froms where the page content some data in html format so i have integrated webview along with image ,lable etc. tag. In side the webview data there are some hyperlink for pdf , image, website which i need to open in different webview/ browser.
For that i have written below code:-

```
void Handle_Navigating(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Url.StartsWith("http"))
        {
            try
            {
                var uri = new Uri(e.Url);

               Device.OpenUri(uri);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

Know the issue is while opening the link its showing address bar which i need to hide.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by it is showing address bar? Do you mean the browsers URL textbox?

Comment: yes its showing url textbox

Comment: Okay you cannot hide that it is out of an application's reach

Comment: so any other better approach to open link from webview.

Comment: You are already on the right path my friend, That is the only and the best approach!

Comment: But if you stil insist on doing the same then you can basically just download the file through your app in to the downloads folder

Comment: Agree with hakim, you cannot hide the address bar in xamarin browser.But you could open this link with a webview for displaying web and HTML content in your app. Unlike `OpenUri`,https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows

Comment: I think you need to ignore the use of Device.OpenUri and build you own app that generates a new webview each time you click on one of your links.  There'd be a bit of work to manage each newly generated instance but it's not impossible.  I couldn't remember if the XF webview showed the address bar and it doesn't ... that's your solution then.